# How to create Insert data via Excel upload which contains half of mysql table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, codeigniter-3

**my Controllers**

```
public function uploadexcel()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls';
    $config['file_name'] = 'doc' . time();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if ($this->upload->do_upload('importexcel')) {
        $file = $this->upload->data();
        $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
        $reader->open('uploads/' . $file['file_name']);
        foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
            $numRow = 1;
            foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                if ($numRow > 1) {
                    $datareceiving = array(
                        'lot_number' =>$this->m_receiving->joinMasterpartBarcode()."/" . $this->m_receiving->bln() . "/" . $this->m_receiving->tgl() . "/" . $this->m_receiving->getSerialNumber(),
                        'upload_id' => $this->m_receiving->get_no_upload_id(),
                        'number_part' => $row->getCellAtIndex(0),
                        'description' => $row->getCellAtIndex(1),
                        'shift' => $row->getCellAtIndex(2),
                        'date_production' => $row->getCellAtIndex(3),
                        'date_receive' => $row->getCellAtIndex(4),
                        'qty_transfer' => $row->getCellAtIndex(5),
                        'pic' => $row->getCellAtIndex(6),
                        'txndate' => $this->m_receiving->today(),
                    );
                    $this->m_receiving->import_data($datareceiving);
                }
                $numRow++;
            }
            $reader->close();
            unlink('uploads/' . $file['file_name']);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Import Excel berhasil');
            redirect('receiving');
        }
    } else {
        echo "Error : " . $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
public function exportexcel()
{
    $get = $this->m_receiving->getAll();
    // Validasi jumlah
    $get->num_rows();
    $writer = WriterEntityFactory::createXLSXWriter();
    $writer->openToBrowser('Receiving.xlsx');
    $header =
        [
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Part Number'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Description'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Shift'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Date Production'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Date Receive'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Qty Transfer'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Customer'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('PIC'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Txndate'),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell('Userid'),
        ];
    $singleRow = WriterEntityFactory::createROW($header);
    $writer->addRow($singleRow);
    $data = array();
    // looping pembacaan Data
    foreach ($get->result() as $key) {
        $data_assetdata = array(
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->part_number),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->description),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->shift),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->date_production),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->date_receive),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->qty_transfer),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->id_customer),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->pic),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->txndate),
            WriterEntityFactory::createCell($key->userid),
        );
        array_push($data, WriterEntityFactory::createRow($data_assetdata));
    }
    $writer->addRows($data);
    $writer->close();
}
```

and this my Model

```
public function lihat()
{
    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
    return $query->result();
}
public function jumlah()
{
    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table);
    return $query->num_rows();
}
public function lihat_id($receive_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->_table, ['receive_id' => $receive_id]);
    return $query->row();
}
public function ubah($data, $receive_id)
{
    $query = $this->db->set($data);
    $query = $this->db->where(['receive_id' => $receive_id]);
    $query = $this->db->update($this->_table);
    return $query;
}
public function tambah($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
}
public function hapus($receive_id)
{
    return $this->db->delete($this->_table, ['receive_id' => $receive_id]);
}
public function getAll()
{
    $this->db->from('receiving');
    return $this->db->get();
}
function get_no_upload_id()
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT MAX(RIGHT(upload_id,2)) AS kd_max FROM receiving WHERE DATE(txndate)=CURDATE()");
    $char = "-";
    $kd = "";
    if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $k) {
            $tmp = ((int)$k->kd_max) + 1;
            $kd = $char . sprintf("%02s", $tmp);
        }
    } else {
        $kd = "1";
    }
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    return date('Ymd') . $kd;
}
function getSerialNumber()
{
    $this->db->select('RIGHT(receiving.receive_id,5) as kode', false);
    $this->db->order_by('receive_id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get('receiving');
    if ($query->num_rows() <> 0) {
        $data = $query->row();
        $kode = intval($data->kode) + 1;
    } else {
        $kode = 1;
    }
    $kode_max = str_pad($kode, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $kode_jadi = $kode_max;
    return $kode_jadi;
}
public function import_data($datareceiving)
{
    $jumlah = count($datareceiving);
    if ($jumlah > 0) {
        // Replcae (namatable , Parameter variable upload)
        $this->db->replace('receiving', $datareceiving);
    }
}
public function today()
{
    $today = date('ymd');
    return $today;
}
public function tgl()
{
    $tgl = date('d');
    return $tgl;
}
public function bln()
{
    $tgl = date('m');
    return $tgl;
}
public function joinMasterpart()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('receiving');
    $this->db->join('master_part', 'receiving.number_part = master_part.part_number','INNER');
    $this->db->join('master_customer', 'master_part.id_customer = master_customer.id_customer','INNER');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
public function joinMasterpartBarcode()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('receiving');
    $this->db->join('master_part', 'receiving.number_part = master_part.part_number','INNER');
    $this->db->join('master_customer', 'master_part.id_customer = master_customer.id_customer','INNER');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
public function detail($part_number)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('receiving');
    $this->db->join('master_part', 'receiving.number_part = master_part.part_number');
    $this->db->where('part_number',$part_number);
    $this->db->join('master_customer', 'master_part.id_customer = master_customer.id_customer');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

and this my Html

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <!-- load sidebar -->
    <?php $this->load->view('partials/sidebar.php') ?>
    <div id="content-wrapper" class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div id="content" data-url="<?= base_url('incoming') ?>">
            <!-- load Topbar -->
            <?php $this->load->view('partials/topbar.php') ?>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <h1 class="h3 m-0 text-gray-800"><?= $title ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="float-right">
                        <a href="<?= base_url('receiving/exportexcel') ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Excel</a>
                        <a href="<?= base_url('receiving/export') ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Export Pdf</a>
                        <a href="<?= base_url('receiving/tambah') ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Tambah</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importdataketua">
                            <i class="fa fa-file-import"></i> Import
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <?php if ($this->session->flashdata('success')) : ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <?= $this->session->flashdata('success') ?>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <?php elseif ($this->session->flashdata('error')) : ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                        <?= $this->session->flashdata('error') ?>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <div class="card shadow">
                    <div class="card-header"><strong>Receiving</strong></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Lot Number</td>
                                        <td>Upload Id</td>
                                        <td>Part Number</td>
                                        <td>Description</td>
                                        <td>Shift</td>
                                        <td>Date Production</td>
                                        <td>Date Receive</td>
                                        <td>Qty Transfer</td>
                                        <td>Pic</td>
                                        <td>Txndate</td>
                                        <td>Id Customer</td>
                                        <td>Customer Name</td>
                                        <td>Action</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <?php $no = 1; ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($all_receiving as $rows_allReceiving) { ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                            <?= $rows_allReceiving->id_customer ?><?= $rows_allReceiving->lot_number ?>
                                                <a href="<?= base_url('receiving/generateBarcode/' . $rows_allReceiving->receive_id) ?>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> Generate</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->upload_id?></td>
                                            <td>
                                            <?= $rows_allReceiving->number_part?>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->description?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->shift?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->date_production ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->date_receive ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->qty_transfer ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->pic ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->txndate ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->id_customer ?></td>
                                            <td><?= $rows_allReceiving->nama_customer ?></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="<?= base_url('receiving/detail/' . $rows_allReceiving->number_part) ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="far fa-folder"></i> Detail</a>
                                                <a onclick="return confirm('apakah anda yakin?')" href="<?= base_url('receiving/hapus/' . $rows_allReceiving->receive_id) ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Hapus</a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- load footer -->
        <?php $this->load->view('partials/footer.php') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="importdataketua" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Import Excel</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?= form_open_multipart('receiving/uploadexcel') ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Upload File</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1" name="importexcel">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-import"></i> Upload</button>
            </div>
            <?= form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $this->load->view('partials/js.php') ?>
<script src="<?= base_url('sb-admin/js/demo/datatables-demo.js') ?>"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('sb-admin') ?>/vendor/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url('sb-admin') ?>/vendor/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function autofill() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'receiving/autofillAjax',
            data: 'part_number' + part_number,
        }).success(function(data) {
            alert('masuk');
        });
    }
</script>
```

**HELP**
am stuck here. I have a project that makes a table receiving with the added method using an import file with Xlsx extension ( Excel ) , they have 21 column inside table mysql and user just import file in a part. and I want it when the upload is successful. All empty data in the table is quickly filled by retrieving data from another table such as vlookup. am using Codeigniter 3.